# Incrementing specific numbers and copy the remaining ones

Tags: batch-file, increment

I'm trying to produce a batch file which perform the following tasks:

1. Read a specific file (later on, I will adapt it to several files);

The file is YAML that contains some lines with key-pairs values and other type of values. Here's an example of my example.yaml:

```
values:
#11233149641  
#1st Values Of This Example file v02
  txt_val1: "0.1"
  txt_val2: "00:22"
  txt_val3: "blue_2 223"
  txt_val4: "1"
  txt_val5: "Hello"
  txt_val6: "45"
  txt_val7: "World"
  
#113641  
#2nd Values
  txt_val8: "1.1"
  txt_val9: "00:33"
  txt_val10: "orange_2"
  txt_val11: "5"
  txt_val12: "Hello"
```

2. Then, for each specific value that I a-priori know, I want to increment them and keep the others "untouched" values.
   For instance, let's say I only want to increment by 1 the **txt_val1**, **txt_val6** and **txt_val8**.
   The values to be incremented are always in quotations marks and could be integers or floats. However, the incremented should always be by 1 no matter if it's one type or another. So, for instance, "1" should become "2" and "1.99" should become "1.100". Also, some floats may start with a decimal 0 like "1.0". And that should become "1.1".

So, following my example given above, the expected result is to have that updated file with the following structure and contents:

```
values:
#11233149641  
#1st Values Of This Example file v02
  txt_val1: "0.2" <-- #INCREMENTED#
  txt_val2: "00:22"
  txt_val3: "blue_2 223"
  txt_val4: "1"
  txt_val5: "Hello"
  txt_val6: "46" <-- #INCREMENTED#
  txt_val7: "World"
  
#113641  
#2nd Values
  txt_val8: "1.2" <-- #INCREMENTED#
  txt_val9: "00:33"
  txt_val10: "orange_2"
  txt_val11: "5"
  txt_val12: "Hello"
```

I have already try several approaches, but none allow me to do exactly this. My current script only increments the expected values and keeps the others txt_XXX values, but all the others like the 1st line is removed. Here's my script:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set filename=example


if exist "%filename%_temp.yaml" del "%filename%_temp.yaml"

for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=:" %%Q in ('type "%filename%.yaml" ^| findstr /n ".*"') do (
  if "%%R"=="" echo. >> "%filename%_temp.yaml"
  
  set incflag=0
  for /f tokens^=1-2^ delims^=^" %%L in ("%%S") do (

    if "%%R"=="  txt_val1" set incflag=1
    if "%%R"=="  txt_val6" set incflag=1
    if "%%R"=="  txt_val8" set incflag=1

    if !incflag! equ 1 (
        for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%N in ("%%M") do (
            if NOT "%%O"=="" (
                set /a tem_val=%%O+1
                echo %%R: "%%N.!tem_val!">>"%filename%_temp.yaml"
            ) else (
                set /a num=%%M+1
                echo %%R: "!num!">>"%filename%_temp.yaml"
            )
        )
    ) else (
        echo %%R >> "%filename%_temp.yaml"
        )
  )
)


del "%filename%"

REM rename temp file to original file name
ren "%filename%_temp" "%filename%"
```

I know that the problem is probably related with the last else statement, but I can't figure out why. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Whilst you may know what each of the target values real names are, _(I'm sure that you've made those up, just for the purpose of this question)_, we'd have to be certain of the format of the string data for each. To explain, `txt_val8` contains a floating point number format string, `txt_val9` contains a time format string, `txt_val10` contains a mixed character format string, and `txt_val11` contains an integer format string. As you can see, many of these would need to be split at certain points or characters, in order to isolate an integer for incrementing. We therefore need that info too!

Comment: Right! The format of the values to be incremented are always a string because they are always inside quoations marks. But the content of each string may vary all the time. However, for this case, I only need to increment integer like ex "2" or floats "2.1"

Comment: Everything read by, or saved to a variable in a batch file would be a string, but the problem is that batch files can only increment an integer, and of the values you've shown in your question, only `txt_val4`, `txt_val6` and `txt_val11` are strings in integer format, any of the rest of them, would require that the string is split in order to isolate only the integer to be incremented, increment it, then rejoin the string to the original format before saving as the new content. The task will be relatively simple for plain integers, but each of the others would require different techniques.

Comment: That is what my script already does. It seperates the strings that I want to increment, increment them and them join them together. The problem is the key values without pairs are not being saved.

Comment: I'm aware of what your code tries to do, however, I'm asking a specific question about the data. Your code is based upon knowing a specific format of key value string with specific key name. All I'm asking is whether your code is always going to be used with those specific key pairs all of the time, because your question does not make that clear. This means that the only people capable of properly assisting you are those who fully understand your intent based upon their interpretation of your submitted code only.

Comment: Ah, ok, i got it know! Sorry. Yes, the code is always going to be used with those specific key pairs.

Comment: For example, your question says that it is incrementing by `1`, when in fact for your floating point one decimal place string data it is incrementing by `0.1`. If that string was `1.9` for instance, then incrementing it by `0.1` the resulting floating point number string would be `2.0`, currently your code would result in `1.10`, is that what you want? If the data was `1.08`, or `1.09`, for instance, you'd have to work around issues with octal numbers, and if it was `1.34`, you'd have `1.35` as the result, which would be incrementing by `0.01`. Do you see what I mean by clarity?

Comment: Yes, i get it and I understand now that type of information is crucial. For this case, is always to increment the last number. So, if it 1 stays 2 but if its 1.9 it should become 1.10 and so on...

Comment: Will it ever be anything other than a one decimal place floating point number? and if not, will the first integer following the decimal point ever be a zero? Please [edit] your question to ensure that everyone fully understands the requirements, they should not have to read through all of theses comments to try to ascertain the specifics of the task.

Comment: Yes, for both lf your questions. Concerning the post edit, I'll do it when I have a chance to grab my pc. Thanks!